# NTAG424 saving initialized keys without master key and decrypt SDM/PICC URL params

Tags: nfc, ndef

I am planning to make a SaaS to verify SDM/PICC URL params for NTAG424 and I'm also planning to make desktop/mobile app to "initialize" user tags and register them to my server.

The idea is anyone can use these apps to initialize their tags and then use my service to verify them.

In the page 24 of AN12196 (personalization), NXP suggests diversifying the keys with a master key. I plan on using that suggested method but the "master key" and "system key" is different for each user.

My question is, if my service doesn't care about editing users' tags, is it enough for me to save on my server for each tag, the final keys generated in the diversification method without having to know their master key and system keys?

I will be able to verify/decrypt SDM/PICC data with the diversified keys without knowing the master/system keys, right? I'm thinking the answer is yes, but just needed a sanity check or if there are other future pitfalls I hadn't thought of.

If so then I could just give them 5 random md5 and don't even need the key diversification process!

Now that I think about it, I think the only reason you need the master key/system key is to be able to generate the same keys if the UID is already in the URL in plaintext, right?

Thanks,
V

Comment: First of all - you are the "owner" of the application of the tag and during personalization period you are going to change the application = file keys to your own, so you already know these keys. For a high security level the tag's UID (and Counter) should NOT transferred in Plain but in encrypted form, for this please use encrypted PICC data. For decryption on backend server side the UID is not know at this moment, so the decryption key is NOT derived from any UID - a detailed example is in the named AN12196 on page 11 ("PICCData Encrypted mirror"). SDMMetaReadKey set to App.KeyX (0x0 - 0x4)

Comment: For "Decryption of SDMENCFileData" see page 13 of the AN12196 document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derivation of die-individual keys from a known Master Key simply makes it easier for the integration, as there is no need for a database, e.g. useful in an offline context.
The tags themselves simply know their 5 application keys, they don't know how these keys were created - so it is up to you whether you derive them from a Master Key, or create random keys (16 bytes) for each tag.
For using this concept with multiple customers, it might make sense to have a plain-text reference to the customer as part of the NDEF URL, so that based on that reference the PICC decryption key can be picked from the database. Then the key for checking/decrypting SDM can be derived or looked up.

Comment: Isn't saving THE master key on every app dangerous? Isn't it better to have my app send me the generated keys upon registration of the tag so I can decode future PICC for it? The second half of your answer is exactly what I was going for with my SaaS. However the first half would be a good idea indeed for a different app idea of mine that could sometimes be offline and use a single reader. I'll keep that in mind! Good answers, thanks.

Comment: @voldomazta: your workflow is fine as long you can **guarantee** that the Smartphone does have an internet connection to your SaaS after tag personalization and before the NTAG424 DNA is used for the first time. Otherwise your customer will have a bad experience on first usage.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Need to make sure I get a 200 OK back from the server before doing anything else with the keys. I'm also going to write-lock it afterwards so after personalization only the server has further need for the keys really.